# Cut Column From Multiple Text Files Into New File

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

I have three text files and I would like to copy/cut the 3rd and 4th columns from each file and then insert them (next to each other) into a new text file.

Here is the contents of one of the text files:

```
03Z 23:00 69.7F 20.9C
04Z 00:00 70.1F 21.2C
05Z 01:00 69.7F 20.9C
06Z 02:00 69.1F 20.6C
07Z 03:00 68.5F 20.3C
08Z 04:00 67.0F 19.4C
09Z 05:00 65.4F 18.6C
10Z 06:00 64.5F 18.1C
11Z 07:00 63.8F 17.7C
12Z 08:00 64.9F 18.3C
13Z 09:00 68.6F 20.3C
14Z 10:00 72.7F 22.6C
15Z 11:00 75.6F 24.2C
16Z 12:00 78.3F 25.7C
17Z 13:00 79.4F 26.4C
18Z 14:00 79.9F 26.6C
```

I'm guessing that `sed` or `awk` would be a good method for achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will collect all of the 3rd and 4th columns concatenated together:

```
awk '{print $3,$4}' file1 file2 file3
```

If you want the 3rd and 4th columns of the second file and the third file to become the 3rd-6th columns of the output, then you need something a little fancier in `bash`:

```
paste <(awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"} {print $3,$4}' file1) \
    <(awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"} {print $3,$4}' file2) \
    <(awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"} {print $3,$4}' file3)
```

Alternatively, you can process each file separate and then `paste` them together at the end.

```
for f in file1 file2 file3
do
    awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"} {print $3,$4}' $f > $f.tmp
done
paste file1.tmp file2.tmp file3.tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cut that is more appropriate in this case:

```
cut -d" " -f3,4 file1 file2 file3 > result.txt
```

Note: if columns are separated by tabs, you can remove `-d" "` since the tabs are the default delimiter for cut.

Note2: if filenames are really numbered you can use `[1-3]` or `[a-c]` etc.:

```
cut -d" " -f3,4 file[1-3] > result.txt
```

Comment: The part of `[1-3]` doesn't work on (my) macOS. Do you know of an alternative?

Comment: @SanderW.vanderLaan: are you sure that `[1-3]` is the problem? Try with an other syntax: `file{1..3}` (note that this assumes that file1, file2 and file3 exist.)